# Download a file from Azure Blob File Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I have a uri of this form:

> abfss://feed-pipeline-workspace@my-company-dev.dfs.core.windows.net/myname/1/staging-snapshot-repo/form/Fulfillment/2022/01/02/snapshot-form-Fulfillment-20220102_000000.parquet

How can I access/download this using a command line tool e.g. `az storage fs file download` ?  I am able to use `az storage fs file upload` but not sure how to piece together `download`.   Any other bash-compatible tool or even `ms.portal.azure.com` approach would also be helpful.

The attempt at using the `az cli` is this

```
az storage fs file download --path myname/1/staging-snapshot-repo/form/Fulfillment/2022/01/02/snapshot-form-Fulfillment-20220102_000000.parquet  
  --account-name feed-pipeline-workspace --share-name myshare  
  -f blob
```

This gives:

> unrecognized arguments: --share-name feed-pipeline-workspace

That is against the documents and examples, in which either `--share-name` or `-s` are valid ( i tried both and they both fail).   Also i don't know what are the valid file-types for the `-f` argument

Note: there is no `container` parameter and so how is it to be specified?

Comment: Yes you need to use `az storage fs file download`. What have you tried so far and what happens / what is the error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I'm not sure how to translate the various portions of the URI to the command line version

Comment: per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-file-download **az storage fs file download** does not support share name argument. What is the path/fs being passed in upload ?

Comment: the `help` message is incorrect it mentions the `--share`

Comment: This might help in your attempts to decode the abfss URI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction-abfs-uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unrecognized arguments: --share-name feed-pipeline-workspace

The error states it doesn't has **`--share-name`**  in the  **`az storage fs file download`** command.

You can follow this [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-file-download) to download the file from Azure storage.

**Command:**

```
az storage fs file download -p dir/a.txt -d test/edit.txt -f fsname --account-name myadlsaccount --account-key 0000-0000
```

Here -f is the filesystem(container)

**Output:**

[image]

**Downloaded file:**
[image]

Comment: The key here is that the `container` is specified via the `-f`. The `help` docs are just sooo wrong.

Comment: In ADLS Gen 2, it's called a file system rather than a container. The naming appears consistent to me but I agree MS have really confused things between ADLS gen1 and ADLS gen2